# Generic function in VHDL to extract an arbitrary byte from a std_logic_vector of any length?

Tags: vhdl

How to write a generic function that will extra a byte from a std_logic_vector based on an index value?

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity tmp is
end entity;

architecture beh of tmp is
```

```vhdl
function get_byte(
    idx: in integer;
    dat: in std_logic_vector
) return std_logic_vector is
    constant msb :integer := (idx+1)*8 - 1;
    constant lsb :integer := idx*8;
    variable ret :std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
    ret := dat(msb downto lsb);
    return ret;
end function;
```

```vhdl
begin

process
    constant vec :std_logic_vector := X"ABCDEF1234567";
    variable b1  :std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    variable m   :line;
begin
    b1 := get_byte(1, vec);
    report "just kidding! end of testbench" severity failure;
end process;

end architecture;
```

Here's the error from my attempt:

```vhdl
C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2021.2\bin\xvhdl.bat --incr --relax --work work tmp.vhd

C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2021.2\bin\xelab.bat tmp -snapshot simout 
Vivado Simulator v2021.2
Copyright 1986-1999, 2001-2021 Xilinx, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Running: C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2021.2/bin/unwrapped/win64.o/xelab.exe tmp -snapshot simout 
Multi-threading is on. Using 10 slave threads.
Starting static elaboration
ERROR: [VRFC 10-1378] slice direction differs from its index type range [C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/tmp/tmp.vhd:19]
ERROR: [XSIM 43-3321] Static elaboration of top level VHDL design unit tmp in library work failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR: [VRFC 10-1378] slice direction differs from its index type
> range

Is resolved by specifying the 'to' vs 'downto' ranges on each std_logic_vector declaration. (the default if not shown is to assumed 0 'to' N, not 'downto' - so when not shown/making simulator choose you are sorta mixing types).

Comment: This will not help with a generic function. The function either needs to detect the direction or normalise the rage, usually via a constant or alias within the function.

Comment: Yes I believe use of /checking 'left and 'right attributes is what is needed here for a generic function, no? https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/attribute.html

Comment: `'ascending` or `'descending` likely more appropriate.  Or use of an alias or constant to lock the range to a specific direction,  as per other answers.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't know how your function will be called and what its parameter will be, a very simple approach consists in creating local copies with known ranges:

```vhdl
function get_byte(idx: natural; dat: std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
  constant size: natural := dat'length;
  constant ldat: std_logic_vector(size-1 downto 0) := dat;
begin
  assert 8*idx+7 <= size report "out of range index" severity failure;
  return ldat(8*idx+7 downto 8*idx);
end function get_byte;
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why, but it works if I write it this way:

```vhdl
function get_byte(
        idx  :in integer;          -- 0=MS-Byte ... n=LS-BYTE
        dat  :in std_logic_vector  -- uncontrained slv is a "to"
                                   -- not a "Downto" vector?
    ) return std_logic_vector is
        constant msb :integer := (idx+1)*8 - 1;
        constant lsb :integer := idx*8;
        variable ret :std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    begin
        ret  := dat(idx*8 + 0) 
             & dat(idx*8 + 1) 
             & dat(idx*8 + 2) 
             & dat(idx*8 + 3) 
             & dat(idx*8 + 4) 
             & dat(idx*8 + 5) 
             & dat(idx*8 + 6) 
             & dat(idx*8 + 7);        
        return ret;
    end function;
```

Comment: No, it certainly does not solve your problem. If your function is called with a `std_logic_vector(L to L+N)` parameter it will return a byte of it, but if it is called with a `std_logic_vector(L downto L-N)` parameter it will return a reversed byte. Check that with `variable v: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"AA"; get_byte(0, v);`. Not mentioning the fact that you could encounter out of range errors. Check with `variable v: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"AA"; get_byte(1, v);`.

Comment: Whatever... it works...  Bit order is easy to change ...